# Browser-based software with backend-frontend and JS

Tags: angular, iframe, architecture, chromium

I am working on a project for a company that developed a software in Delphi. The software revolved around a minimalistic browser as the center piece of the software. While using the browser the webpages are analyzed, patterns are recognized, data is saved etc.

As the analysis is getting more complex we plan to switch to a backend / frontend approach. Furthermore we would like to develop the software using JS (more specifically Angular) and then for bundle it using electron or something similar. Long-term goal would be to make it available also in browsers as a SaaS.

Now the problem is the "browser in browser". I would still like to give the user the option to interact with an artificial browser within my app. The following were things I though about but that do not quite get the job done:

1. Working with iframes - iFrames seem to not give enough information about the pages the user is currently on (from what I know). At least I would need the current link and some information about the state (like cookies etc.)
2. Completely disallowing interaction on the webpage and only displaying an image stream from out python backend that would then use selenium. (Not really an option)
3. Building the software as a very sophisticated chrome extension. But I don't think that would be a viable option for us and our customers.

I don't want the page analysis taking place in the frontend, therefore even with the iframe approach I would try to sync the current iframe browser state with the backend selenium browser and perform all analysis in the backend.

I know this is quite specific, but I would be very happy for any links or ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I totally understand, but here's some ideas & thoughts.

Separate concerns.  You seem to be doing two things: allowing users to see / interact with the content in the browser, and performing analysis. - hence the browser in browser problem.  Can you separate these out?

E.g. have one browser which people see, and another which does the analysis?  If the analysis is supposed to keep up with any user interactions then that's probably not going to work.  But the general idea might if you do it a different way.  The trick is just to somehow not have one thing do two complex jobs.

For example, (totally unrelated to your problem) I built a CMS years ago which included content editing and search.  I ended up storing the content twice:

- Once using [element].innerText to get the content as users saw it, which I stored away and used for text-based searching.
- Once using [element].innerHTML to store the raw HTML for serving and future content editing.

Back to your problem: for the analysis - do you even need a browser to do that?  (I guess you would if the pages content is in anyway enabled through client-side scripts or AJAX calls).

I don't know about how other browser vendors do it, but with Microsoft's WebView control the browser is somewhat cut-down.  From memory, it's not just that it seems to have functionality missing, its like they deliberately retarded it for security reasons or something.  The point being, doing stuff with or through a browser or embedded browser control will not be straight forward.